# How to write a WebService that will accept Json with "Multi Type Property"?

Tags: c#, json, web-services, wcf, asp.net-web-api

Context:
Cust has a service that send the following json. He can easly change the target of that query but not the query it self.

I have to build a WebService that accept query like the following JSON.
While I will have no issue handeling the Json, I have an issue trying to define the method/interface that will accept a query like this.

The issue comes from Houses > Things: It's a dictionary of string, "`objectThing`" where "`objectThing`" has a property value that may hold multiple type.
EG:

- int ,  `"Value": 42`
- string , `"Value": "Catty"`
- string array, `"Value": ["Book1", "Book2", "Book3"]`
- object , A limited List of Object Type

  ```
  "Value": 
        {
          "PeopleId": "1234ABCD",
          "Name": "John"
        }
  ```
- object array, An Array of with limited List of Object Type

  ```
  "Value": [
        {
          "PeopleId": "1234ABCD",
          "Name": "John"
        },
        {
          "PeopleId": "0000AAAA",
          "Name": "Doe"
        }
   ]
  ```

  Value is not Dynamic for me. It's within a limited list of Type that I can define.

Json Example:

```
{
    "RootID"    : "0123456",
    "FooID"     : "0123456",    
    "BarID"     : "0123456",
    "Houses"    :[
        {
            "OwnerId"   : "0123456",
            "Date"      : 1890895600000,
            "Location"  : {
                "Latitude"  : -1,
                "Longitude" : -1
            },

            "Things" :{
                "1" :{
                    "Label": "Books",                   
                    "Type" : "List",
                    "Value": ["Book1", "Book2", "Book3"]
                },
                "2" :{
                    "Label": "Cat",                 
                    "Type" : "Text",
                    "Value": "Catty"
                },
                "3" :{
                    "Label": "A Number",                    
                    "Type" : "Int",
                    "Value": 42
                },
                "4" :{
                    "Label": "Peoples",                 
                    "Type" : "People",
                    "Value": [
                        {
                          "PeopleId": "1234ABCD",
                          "Name": "John"
                        },
                        {
                          "PeopleId": "0000AAAA",
                          "Name": "Doe"
                        }
                    ]
                }               
            }
        },
        {       
            "OwnerId"   : "111111",
            "Things" :{}
        },
        {       
            "OwnerId"   : "000001",
            "Things" :{}
        }   
    ]
}
```

And the Class definition, If I were to deserialize this Json into a proper type:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Globalization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

public partial class QueryRoot
{
    [JsonProperty("RootID")]
    public string RootId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("FooID")]
    public string FooId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("BarID")]
    public string BarId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Houses")]
    public List<House> Houses { get; set; }
}

public partial class House
{
    [JsonProperty("OwnerId")]
    public string OwnerId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Date", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public long? Date { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Location", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public Location Location { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Things")]
    public Dictionary<string, Thing> Things { get; set; }
}

public partial class Location
{
    [JsonProperty("Latitude")]
    public long Latitude { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Longitude")]
    public long Longitude { get; set; }
}

public partial class Thing
{
    [JsonProperty("Label")]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Value")]
    public ThingValue Value { get; set; }
}

public partial class ValueClass
{
    [JsonProperty("PeopleId")]
    public string PeopleId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public partial struct ValueElement
{
    public string String;
    public ValueClass ValueClass;

    public static implicit operator ValueElement(string String) => new ValueElement { String = String };
    public static implicit operator ValueElement(ValueClass ValueClass) => new ValueElement { ValueClass = ValueClass };
}

public partial struct ThingValue
{
    public List<ValueElement> AnythingArray;
    public long? Integer;
    public string String;

    public static implicit operator ThingValue(List<ValueElement> AnythingArray) => new ThingValue { AnythingArray = AnythingArray };
    public static implicit operator ThingValue(long Integer) => new ThingValue { Integer = Integer };
    public static implicit operator ThingValue(string String) => new ThingValue { String = String };
}

public partial class QueryRoot
{
    public static QueryRoot FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QueryRoot>(json, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
}

public static class Serialize
{
    public static string ToJson(this QueryRoot self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
}

internal static class Converter
{
    public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
        DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
        Converters =
        {
            ThingValueConverter.Singleton,
            ValueElementConverter.Singleton,
            new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
        },
    };
}

internal class ThingValueConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type t) => t == typeof(ThingValue) || t == typeof(ThingValue?);

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type t, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        switch (reader.TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.Integer:
                var integerValue = serializer.Deserialize<long>(reader);
                return new ThingValue { Integer = integerValue };
            case JsonToken.String:
            case JsonToken.Date:
                var stringValue = serializer.Deserialize<string>(reader);
                return new ThingValue { String = stringValue };
            case JsonToken.StartArray:
                var arrayValue = serializer.Deserialize<List<ValueElement>>(reader);
                return new ThingValue { AnythingArray = arrayValue };
        }
        throw new Exception("Cannot unmarshal type ThingValue");
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object untypedValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var value = (ThingValue)untypedValue;
        if (value.Integer != null)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value.Integer.Value);
            return;
        }
        if (value.String != null)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value.String);
            return;
        }
        if (value.AnythingArray != null)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value.AnythingArray);
            return;
        }
        throw new Exception("Cannot marshal type ThingValue");
    }

    public static readonly ThingValueConverter Singleton = new ThingValueConverter();
}

internal class ValueElementConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type t) => t == typeof(ValueElement) || t == typeof(ValueElement?);

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type t, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        switch (reader.TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.String:
            case JsonToken.Date:
                var stringValue = serializer.Deserialize<string>(reader);
                return new ValueElement { String = stringValue };
            case JsonToken.StartObject:
                var objectValue = serializer.Deserialize<ValueClass>(reader);
                return new ValueElement { ValueClass = objectValue };
        }
        throw new Exception("Cannot unmarshal type ValueElement");
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object untypedValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var value = (ValueElement)untypedValue;
        if (value.String != null)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value.String);
            return;
        }
        if (value.ValueClass != null)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value.ValueClass);
            return;
        }
        throw new Exception("Cannot marshal type ValueElement");
    }

    public static readonly ValueElementConverter Singleton = new ValueElementConverter();
}
```

I already have a WCF Service that handles Json. It work fine the issue is declaring the method/interface that will accept this kind of query. 
If WCF Web Service is a limiting factor, or if  (ASP.NET/Core) Web APIs provides an easier path it's welcom.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465858/how-can-i-accept-arbitrary-json-objects-in-my-rest-wcf-service.

Comment: [Anonymous and Weakly-Typed Objects with web api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#json_anon)

Answer (score 1):

You can receive a JSON string and convert it to an object. Here is a demo:

```
      [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        Stream s = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream; 
        byte[] b = new byte[s.Length];
         s.Read(b, 0, (int)s.Length);
         string jsontext = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b);
        var productProperty = JsonHelper.JsonDeserialize<School>(jsontext); //Deserialize JSON strings to objects
        return "Hello World";
    }
```

This is the method in WebService.

```
[DataContract]
public class School
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ClassroomId { set; get; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Student> StudentList { set; get; }
}
[DataContract]
public class Student
{
    [DataMember]
    public int StudentId { set; get; }
    [DataMember]
    public string StudentName { set; get; }
}
```

This is the object to be converted by JSON string.

```
    public class JsonHelper
{
    public static string JsonSerializer<T>(T t)
    {
        var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        ser.WriteObject(ms, t);
        string jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        ms.Close();
        return jsonString;
    }
    public static T JsonDeserialize<T>(string jsonString)
    {
        var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
        var obj = (T)ser.ReadObject(ms);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

To deserialize JSON characters into objects,there are many open-source class libraries. I use the DatacontractJsonSerializer that comes with .net version 3.5 or above.I wrote a JsonHelper class.

Comment: `WebInvoke(Method = "POST")` and using the body with `RequestContext.RequestMessage.GetBody`. 
Is something that I didn't consider. And asking to send it as `Content-Type:text/plain`.

Comment: I will also give the `HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream`.

Comment: Well You can expect weeks before this get to hit a sand box. This part seems to not be use by the final cust , while it's in the 100% coverage, I'm not sure any one will live long enought to see it. I will give it a try out side of work for personal developpement. But didn't find the time and energy.