# wcf json array with variable name not deserializing

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, wcf, model-binding

I have created a WCF service that accepts, for example, this json:

```
{
  "type": "despatch",
  "client_ref": "ORD00001",
  "date_despatched": "2015-01-01T17:27:38+00:00",
  "postage_method": "Royal Mail 1st Class Packet",
  "tracking_number": "GB1010101010A",
  "items": [
    {
      "client_ref": "ABC123",
      "quantity": 1,
      "serial_numbers": {
        "ABC123": [
          "SERIAL0001"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

An issue arises when trying to deserialize the "serial_numbers" element as the array element name is unknown - it is a variable that changes with each entry in "items".

The service works fine except the "serial_numbers" data is blank after deserialization.

Here is the operation contract definition

```
        [OperationContract(Name = "JAJTracking")]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "JAJTracking?W={W}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        JANDJResponse ProcessTracking(string W, JAndJDespatch jjdesp);
```

I've tried using a "Dictionary" to store the serial_numbers data as from searching this appeared to be the only way to go.

```
    public class JAndJDespatch
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string type { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string client_ref { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string date_despatched { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string postage_method { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string tracking_number { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<JAndJDespatchItems> items { get; set; }
    }

    public class JAndJDespatchItems
    {
        [DataMember]
        public object UsedForKnownTypeSerializationObject;
        [DataMember]
        public string client_ref { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public Int32 quantity { get; set; }
        [JsonExtensionData]
        public Dictionary<string, object> serial_numbers { get; set; }
    }
```

If I hard-code the json message as a string in the 'ProcessTracking' method & run it the deserialization process works perfectly & I can access the serial_number data.

However when the json is passed through the wcf service the rest of the data is deserialized but the "serial_numbers" data is missing.

Is there something obvious I am doing wrong or is it not possible to deserialize this type json data using a WCF service?

If not possible to do this via wcf how can I do it?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2307367/6292693) help?

Comment: WCF's `DataContractJsonSerializer` does not support deserializing JSON **objects** to dictionaries, it only supports deserializing JSON **arrays of key/value pairs** to dictionaries.  See [Make ASP.NET WCF convert dictionary to JSON, omitting "Key" & "Value" tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7590088) or [How to return a Dictionary of custom type values as a regular JSON object from a WCF REST method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35490329/3744182) or [Serialize C# Dictionary as JSON object using WCF with HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77482970/3744182).

Comment: JsonExtensionData is used for deserialization and not for serialization. Usually we use **JsonConvert.SerializeObject** to convert dictionary data into Json string data.

    Dictionary<string,object> serial_numbers = new Dictionary<string, object>() {
        {"ABC123","SERIAL0001"},
    };
    string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(serial_numbers);


Next, you can convert this Json string into a Json object and then splice it together.

Comment: Apologies just realised I typed serialize instead of deserialize above! Thanks for the responses so far - have tried a few things based on them but still can't get it to deserialize the serial_numbers element when the json is passed through a wcf service. Have a few more things to try so will keep at it.

Comment: `[JsonExtensionData]` is from Json.NET or System.Text.Json, but WCF uses `DataContractJsonSerializer` **which does not support free-form JSON, and does not by default accept dictionaries as JSON objects.** You may need to modify your `JANDJResponse` method to accept a `Stream`, and do all the parsing manually. See e.g. [How can I accept arbitrary JSON objects in my REST WCF service?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11465858), ...

Comment: ...  [WCF "Raw" programming model (Web) - receiving arbitrary data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/carlosfigueira/wcf-raw-programming-model-web-receiving-arbitrary-data) and [WCF - Supporting raw requests for individual operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/carlosfigueira/wcf-supporting-raw-requests-for-individual-operations) and/or ...

Comment: ... [Reading A Raw Binary Post Buffer](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:BNLjcci5mSYJ:https://qa.social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fc8cbad8-a8fc-46d6-b15f-5ae712ca56cd/reading-a-raw-binary-post-buffer?forum%3Dwcf&sca_esv=585309262&strip=1&vwsrc=0) and [How to: Create a Service That Accepts Arbitrary Data using the WCF REST Programming Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/create-a-service-arbitrary-data-using-wcf).

Comment: I tried writing WCF services directly using the **Console App**. The Result is that its return value is serial_numbers":**[{"Key":"ABC123","Value":"SERIAL0001"}]}**. Its return values exist in "Key" and "Value".

Comment: I eventually got it going last week - I had to first use the solution in this to get access to the stream as the request was always going to be set to application/json  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34742485/how-to-pass-json-string-and-deserialize-in-wcf/54954261#54954261 - I then just parsed the data I needed out of the Dictionary Value elements, knowing it was going to be a string representation of a json array.

Comment: @kbbucks - maybe you should add that as a self-anwer then since you had to pull together content from multiple preceding answers.